# Why my python aiogram bot works so slow with openai-api?

Tags: python, async-await, openai-api, aiogram

I am making an inline bot in Telegram using Python and the aiogram library. I am using the Chat GPT API(https://github.com/openai/openai-python) to respond to inline queries.
I handle it with this code:

```
bot = Bot(token=settings.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_handler(inline_query: types.InlineQuery):
    print("getting.....")
    text = inline_query.query
    short_answer = await create_short_answer(text)
    message = "Q: " + inline_query.query + "\n\n" + "A: " + short_answer

    print("answerring....")

    input_content = types.InputTextMessageContent(message)
    item = types.InlineQueryResultArticle(id='1', title='Answer',
                                          input_message_content=input_content)
    await bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, results=[item], cache_time=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

And this is my functions to create a short answer:

```
async def create_short_answer(text):
    res = await __answer(
        text=text,
        system_message="Your answers must be very short. Your answers must be less than 15 words",
    )
    return res

async def __answer(text, system_message=''):
    completion = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": system_message},
            {"role": "user", "content": text}
        ]
    )

    answer = completion.choices[0].message.content
    logging.debug(f'answer for \'{text}\':\n{answer}')
    return answer
```

However, when sending a large number of requests(21 requests) to my bot at once (something like stress tests), I encounter the issue where in the inline_handler function, "getting..." is printed 4 times, and then "answering" is printed 4 times, and so on. It feels like each request is blocking one core (I have 4 cores) and my code actually becomes non-asynchronous.

I want to make my bot fully asynchronous so that it can handle hundreds of requests simultaneously. What I do wrong?

P.S first of all I've tried to use another bot api - telebot, and encountered the same issue(

Comment: I tried to make a lot of requests to openai with await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
and 20+ requests ended in 3 seconds, so there is no problem with openai token limit or throttling in their code